# Python: getaddrinfo and gethostbyname do not return port numbers

Tags: python, c++, embedded, port, marmalade

I've embedded python 2.7.1 into a C++ based app (marmalade)

running the example from:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html

## input

```
import socket
socket.getaddrinfo("www.python.org", 80, 0, 0, socket.SOL_TCP)
```

## return

```
[(2, 3, 3, '', ('23.235.47.175', 0))]

DEBUG:
SOCKET: s3eInetAton: 'www.python.org'
SOCKET: s3eInetLookup: 'www.python.org'
SOCKET: s3eInetLookup (synchronous): done DNS: '23.235.47.175:0'
IWCRT: gethostbyname www.python.org -> 4a700360
```

However it should be like this, with a port not equal to zero

[(2, 1, 6, '', ('xx.xx.xx.xx', **80**)]

Same with getaddrinfo:

## input

```
import sys, socket

result = socket.getaddrinfo("python.org", None, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

for item in result:
    print (item[4])
```

## return

```
('140.211.10.69', 0)
```

---

('xx.xx.xx.xx', **80**)

still no port

---

- I've run the script outside of the home directory
- I've combed through pyconfig.h to see if there are any settings are missing (that I see)
- I've searched for a list of common python socket settings no where to be found ( you'd think it would be easy )

any ideas on what could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think getaddrinfo() or gethostbyname() returns ports along with IP. You can check the following link [getaddrinfo()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) and RFC-2553.